# Rename "IP" tag to "IP- address"

Tags: support, retag-request

[ip](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip) only has 11 questions right now, but because of the possible ambiguity between "Intellectual Property" and "Internet Protocol" (and the fact that there is no tag wiki) it should be renamed to [ip-address](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip-address), probably with a synonym from the old [ip](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip).

All of the existing 11 questions are about IP meaning "Internet Protocol".

Comment: Eh, does this actually confuse anyone? Also, it's only 11 questions, you could just retag them.

Comment: @YannisRizos I could, but I can't do the synonym half of it.

Comment: You don't really need the synonym. If you retag all [ip] questions to [ip-address], the [ip] tag will be cleared eventually (and won't be usable by new-ish users).

Comment: @YannisRizos Well, okay, but I also created a tag wiki entry for [tag:ip] which will be lost

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the ambiguity concern. While it might not be a big issue, it should be changed.

I created the new tag and copied the existing tag wiki text that you created for the old tag. I edited the existing questions to use it. One question was improperly tagged so I just removed the tag from that question.

Now that no more questions are tagged with IP it will self-delete.